# ¿Cómo puedo llevar los cambios de una rama a otra sin destruirla?

Tags: git

Empecé hace relativamente poco con git y tengo un problema tengo una rama develop y mi rama y quisiera bajar los cambios de develop a mi rama sin que se borre develop, ¿Cómo podría hacerlo?

Comment: Las mezclas no son destructivas para la rama origen (aunque modifican obviamente la rama destino). En principio bastaría que hicieras un `git checkout master` para cambiarte a la rama master y desde ella hacer un `git merge develop` para mezclar los cambios de la rama develop en la rama master. La otra rama sigue existiendo y puedes volver a ella con `git checkout develop`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para actualizar tu branch sin afectar al branch develop
Tenes 2 opciones

**Opcion 1**
Se recomienda usar esta opcion si en general trabajaste sobre un feature nuevo o si estas tocando archivos que otra personas no estan editando, ya que sino el merge te va a tirar muchos conflictos y para eso te recomiendo la opcion 2

```
#Actualizando lo ultimo de develop.
git checkout  develop 
git pull 

# Recordar que siempre tenes que estar PARADO sobre el branch que queres actualizar
# En este caso como queres actualizar tu branch y no el de develop
# Entonces si haces un git status, te deberia decir que estas parado sobre TU BRANCH
git checkout branchdev 
git merge develop
```

**Opcion 2**
Lo mas seguro para no conflictuar tu branch, te sugiero los siguientes pasos:

Esto lo recomiendo SOLO si sabes que el merge entre DEVELOP y tu branch puede tener varios conflictos lo cual te puede llevar tiempo resolver :D

```
// Me voy a la rama de develop
git checkout develop

//Actualiza el branch develop con lo ultimo
git pull

//Vuelvo a branch del desarrollador, osea el tuyo
git checkout branchdev

// Crea un nuevo branch LOCAL desde tu branch
git checkout -b mergeMyBranchWithDevelop

//Actualiza tu branch con lo ultimo de desarrollo. sin conflictuar tu branch original
git merge develop


//Una vez que tengas resuelto los conflictos, si es que hubo alguno, volves al tuyo original
git checkout branchdev

// Actualiza tu branchdev original SIN conflictos ni problemas :D 
git merge mergeMyBranchWithDevelop

//Tu branch ya quedo actualizado :D  y podes borrar el branch mergeMyBranchWithDevelop :D
```

Espero que te sirva, en general siempre se hace la opcion1, pero sino tenes mucha experiencia con git te recomiendo la opcion 2 hasta que obtengas mas confianza. :D

Comment: la opcion 2 es un overkill, pero para una persona que no tiene experiencia con git, podria ser lo mas recomendable hasta que logre aprender los conceptos y no se sienta intimidado/intimidada por los pasos involucrados y por ver un conflicto en un archivo... o varios :-D. bien por esa!!

Comment: Si pienso igual, la opcion2 es para los juniors en git, porque tengo muchos conocidos que realmente le tienen mucho miedo a git y bueno es una forma bastante amigable de ir tomando confianza.